# Ionic build creates an old version of my app even if I create a new blank app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Every time I run `ionic cordova build android` and then `ionic cordova emulate android`, I get a version my app from maybe a month ago. Here's what I've tried:

1. I've deleted files including deleting them from `/platforms/android` to no effect.
2. I've tried updating my version number in my config.xml file.
3. I've tried deleting the APK and various other files from `/build/android`
4. I tried creating a new ionic app with `ionic start` and then after cding into the new directory for my new project and running the same two commands, I got the old version of my *other* app.
5. I've tried removing and then adding back cordova android with both the commands `ionic cordova rm/add platform android` and `cordova rm/add platform android` and these cause some bizarre responses. With the ionic prefix, the remove command works fine but on add, I get this:

...

```
C:\Users\max\Documents\omsLibrary>ionic cordova platform add android
cordova platform add android --save
√ Running command - done!
ionic cordova resources android --force
√ Collecting resource configuration and source images - done!
Platform android not detected. Would you like to install it? (Y/n)
```

Update: after globally installing cordova, I no longer get the above on add. I just get this:

```
cordova platform add android --save
× Running command - failed!
[WARN] Platform already added. Saving platforms to config.xml.
> cordova platform save
√ Running command - done!
```

<strike>[ERROR] No platforms detected. Please run: ionic cordova platform add</strike>

<strike>I can keep doing this forever if I want but it will keep giving me the same circular instructions.</strike>

I have no problems at all with `ionic serve`.

Here is what I get from `ionic info` (updated after following Suraj Rao's suggestion):

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\max\Documents\omsLibrary\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.13.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.13.1

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.7
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v6.9.2
    npm               : 5.4.2
    OS                : Windows 10

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Here's what I get from the `cordova ls` command:

```
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-inapppurchase 1.1.0 "In App Purchase"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

What is the deal here? Do I just wipe and reinstall everything related to ionic and cordova? Thanks to anyone who can provide assistance!

Comment: you are still getting `cordova platform add android --save
× Running command - failed!` ?

Comment: You're right. I no longer keep getting notifications that Android platform is not installed. I still do get this when I run the emulate or build commands though. Note that this a RESPONSE. I am not entering the command "cordova platform add android --save". ionic does it automatically when I enter the build or emulate commands.This is the response I get:cordova platform add android --save
× Running command - failed!
[WARN] Platform already added. Saving platforms to config.xml.

Comment: Remove the platform with the remove command `ionic cordova platform rm android --save` and then do `ionic cordova platform add android --save`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this one out. Apparently, when I was first starting the project and I didn’t know what I was doing (not that I really know what I’m doing now!), I copied the contents of my project folder (`max/documents/myapp`) into its parent folder (`max/documents`) because I was making some change that I was worried would break things. I completely forgot I had done this. When I deleted all those files from my `documents` folder, it worked!

So what I think was happening was the different mechanisms in the build process used different logic to determine where the project and platforms folders are.The `add platform` command was adding the platform to its right location, but the find platform command was looking I suppose in `/max` rather than `/max/documents` for the platforms folder and failing to find it. Then the `copy project files to build folder` command was finding the correct destination but looking in `/documents` rather than `/documents/myapp` to find the files to be copied over to `/max/documents/platforms/android` and finding the code from my ancient version of the app.

Answer (score 2):

Your app is updating background from your ionic dashboard. 
So you can delete app from dashboard:

1. Go to your ionic dashboard
https://dashboard.ionicframework.com

2. Delete app

or you can remove update plugin (cordova-plugin-ionic):

3. Open terminal and

```
cd your_project_folder
```

4. Uninstall cordova-plugin-ionic

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-ionic
```

or both.

Comment: uninstalling cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-ionic helped me

Answer (score 1):

> cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed

You need to install `cordova` globally along with ionic cli.

Do:

```
npm i cordova -g
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, Suraj. I tried that, but I'm still seeing the exact same issue. Ionic is even loading files that I've deleted. Is there some caching system here or build list that is somehow not being updated? I even just tried deleting everything in /platforms and adding android as a platform again.